# Accessing one Frames content

Tags: javascript, html

As a college project I have been trying to make a modular website that can easily be adjusted for whatever page there is so I tried making two frames where pressing a link on one frame changes the other.

The manual function seems to work on the page but I am unable to bind the link outside of the frame to run the function

Comment: Please do not use frames in the year of 2017.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Then what do you suggest to use instead

Comment: Instead of frames, dynamic content should be loaded via AJAX. Most of this can be simplified by using a well-established framework such as Angular with its routing module. For non dynamic content that you wish to use on multiple pages in your website, consider using a templating engine on your server.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 well there goes my plan of using things I already know.
I'm going to start looking into these then

Comment: Be prepared to set up an environment for transpiling your code if you are using a modern framework, though it should be fairly straightforward if you follow the guides online. Depending on the complexity of your project, you might not need a full-blown framework but it's recommended (sometimes just jQuery might already be enough.) Best of luck on your project.